# How to get health data from my iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, export, ios

I'm a Mac/iPhone lucky owner and also a big fan of data analysis. Maybe someone know how to import personal health data from my iPhone to my Mac?

Comment: Is there a particular application you have been using to collect this data?

Comment: This might be better suited to apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6582940